# how to monitor and restart two ruby scripts with God?

Tags: ruby, god

I have been able to run a single god file for a single ruby script as such:

```
God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "twilio"
  w.start = "ruby ~/code/site/iron.io/twilio-listen.rb"
  w.keepalive
end
```

But I have two scripts and want to have God watch both of them (twilio-listen.rb and slack-listen.rb)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to specify watches for both in the same God config file.  You might also want to add a group called `listeners` if you ever needed to stop or restart them together.  E.g.,

```
God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "twilio"
  w.group = "listeners"
  w.start = "ruby ~/code/site/iron.io/twilio-listen.rb"
  w.keepalive
end

God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "slack"
  w.group = "listeners"
  w.start = "ruby ~/code/site/iron.io/slack-listen.rb"
  w.keepalive
end
```

Comment: How would I run it. Just put the code in a god confit file?

Comment: I actually did this by using the load command with each block in its own file. But it doesn't restart the slack process

Comment: https://gist.github.com/konacaret/057ae01f992e9ec28087 has the basic set up I used to monitor two simple scripts.  I used `bundle exec god -c simple.god` to start God.  `shell_output.txt` shows both watches being picked up and used to start, restart, and stop the scripts.  If you still have trouble getting your config to work, please update the question with your watch files and config file & I'll take a look.  FWIW - I am using the latest version of God: `Version 0.13.7`

Comment: Nice!  I did your way instead of load and it works!  Is there a way to send a block to restart?  When it fails I want my listener to not only restart by send a message to the listener to small it has restarted. This is Great!

Comment: You can try adding some code that is called on the transition from `:restart` to `:up` that sends a message to the listener once the process is known to be up and running after restart.  The [God 'Advanced Configuration with Transitions and Events' wiki section](http://godrb.com/#wiki-_advanced_configuration_with_transitions_and_events) should point you in the right direction on how to do that.